# Change Windows 7 start menu height depending on monitor size?

Tags: windows-7, external-display, start-menu

I know I can change the height of the Windows 7 Start Menu so that includes more or fewer recently used apps, etc.

But I have a netbook with a tiny screen that I plug into a decent sized LCD most of the time at home.

Is there a way to get Win7 to use a taller Start menu with more items when I'm using the LCD and a shorter Start menu with fewer items when using the netbook's built in screen?

(I'm a programmer so capable of technical solutions if there's no ready-made solution.)

Answer (score 2):

When you change the 2 **Start menu size** values here:

[image: 1]

What changes are these 2 values:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"Start_MinMFU"=dword:0000000a
"Start_JumpListItems"=dword:0000000a
```

You can simply create .REG files or even batch files that use the **reg** command to change the values as required.

Comment: I can certainly make my own little tool by combining the details @magicandre1981 provided in his answer about the resolution change even with the details you've provided about the registry keys - thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, and maybe you can share the app and source on GitHub or elsewhere and add the link here. (BTW, I used Process Monitor to locate the reg keys. Fantastic utility as are all the rest in the SysInternals suite - never leave home without 'em! :)

Comment: Looking into programming languages right now (-;

Comment: I thought you had everything at hand! If you're gonna go to the trouble of *looking into* programming languages, identifying one, downloading the compiler/tool chain and *then* hacking something together, why not simply create batch files and shortcuts? Of course, it's always fun to do these little projects, so you might want to [check out .NET/C# for this](http://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1649/Csharp.aspx?df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&select=1756582&tid=1756582), along with the Visual Studio Express programs.

Comment: Basically I haven't fiddled with this stuff since the plain C Win32 API was most used. Since those days I was mostly in Perl then JavaScript due to my interest in cross-platform projects. Now I have to see if I should take up C# or if it's still possible in C... or even an excuse to teach myself some node.js or Python if they are up to such low-level shenanigans (-:

Answer (score 1):

Create your own tool which [handles the screen resolution change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged.aspx) and changes the amount of displayed recent items in the registry with your tool.

Comment: Do you know what bits of the registry would be relevant and if changes would be reflected immediately?

Comment: I don't know the key, but use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html to monitor the Explorer.exe, make the changes in the UI and the Tool tells you which keys were modified.